# Monetdb.read.csv error in importing .csv file to a new monetdb table

Tags: r, monetdb

I am trying to import in a table a large csv file to monetdb. I am using monetdb.R to so.

```
monetdb.read.csv(conn, file="C:/CoreData/data_master.csv", "coredata", 1000, delim=",")
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :Unable to execute statement 'COPY OFFSET 2 INTO coredata FROM 'C:\CoreData\data_master.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',','\n','"' NULL as...'. Server says '!could not open file 'C:CoreDatadata_master.csv': No such file or directory'
```

My system specifications are as follows:

```
Sys.info()
                 sysname                      release                      version                     nodename 
               "Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1"               "thepc" 
                 machine                        login                         user               effective_user 
                "x86-64"                  "theuser"  "R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)"                  "theuser"                  "theuser"
```

I have the impression that the directory error that is throwns has to do with the parsing of the directory address. Or perhaps the command reads only from a specific location that I do not know.

I have also tried to declare newlines, na.strings etc without any success.
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: what happens if you call ```monetdb.read.csv(conn, file="C:\\CoreData\\data_master.csv", "coredata", 1000, delim=",")
``` ?

Comment: It is the same error. I have also used quadruple \ but the error persists. I have also tried to call the file from the same wd without success.

Comment: May be that helps towards the solution. When I choose indeed a file that does not exist I get the following error:
`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/data_master.csv': No such file or directory`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is here: quoteIfNeeded  [link](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.4/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-db/org/netbeans/api/db/sql/support/SQLIdentifiers.Quoter.html)

Comment: @Michalis could you post a few records from `data_master.csv` on the internet somewhere so we can test this out ourselves?  just the first ten records or so should be sufficient.  thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! The problem is that I had the same issues while using `data(iris)` . I have written a small csv file and the I have tried to bulk copy it to `monetdb` I manage to solve partially the issue by tweaking the code for `monetdb.read.csv` I have commented out the function `quoteIfneeded` as well as tghe function `normalizepath`. I think the latter is native in base. However, I think the command `dbSendUpdate` re-removes the `\\`. That is why I think `normalizepath` wasn't necessary from my tweaked code. Then the `COPY .. OFFSET` works perfectly.

Comment: hi, `MonetDBLite` (on CRAN) now replaces `MonetDB.R` and runs embedded (like `RSQLite`).  for more detail, see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/README.md